# Best and Fastest way to edit the CSS in JSP pages

Tags: css, jsp

Please provide the Best and Fastest way to edit the CSS in JSP pages. I am presently trying to use brackets software but getting issue.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Regards,
Lakshman E

Answer (score 0):

My personal preferences are not to mix different technologies. 
Each should be stored in its own file(s):  css, js

Then use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

to include them in jsp/html.